# Maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing a prime $p$ is $(p,f(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Algebra qualifying exam question here. Suppose that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and it contains a prime number $p$. Show that $I=(p,f(x))$, for some $f(x)$ monic in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$.

I'm very stuck on this. A friend told me to try Bezout's identity on $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$, but I don't see how I can take a gcd downstairs in this ring and pull information back upstairs to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I could also be misinterpreting what they meant by "use Bezout's identity". Any hints would be tremendous. Thank you!

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, so $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is a PID...

Answer (score 2):

The quotient map $p:\mathbb{Z}[X]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]/I$ factor by a map $q:\mathbb{Z}/p[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[X]/I$. The kernel of this map is a maximal ideal $J$ since $\mathbb{Z}[X]/I$ is a field. Since $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a field, $\mathbb{Z}/p[X]$ is a principal domain. This implies that there exists a irreducible polynomial $f$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p[X]$ which generates $J$. Up to a coefficient, you can suppose that $f$ is monic since $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a field.